# my Xamarin android application time out when uploading data to soap web service

Tags: android, wcf, xamarin, soap, xamarin.android

When my Xamarin android mobile application updating data to the windows soap web API application, sometime take a long time. I thought that it happened because of my soap application issue. but the soap web API application works fine when I run the console application by updating data. I am new to Xamarin. I am in real trouble now. some time works some time hang and time out.

I double-check in the windows mobile app to update that windows soap API it is working fine. can update more than 100-time data in a few seconds.

where should be wrong?
Here is the code.

Comment: this is the code - for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
 {      
   string r = SysConfigur.sop.WSUpdate("WA21313" + i, "AABCD12", 
   DateTime.Now.ToString(), "A");
 }

Comment: It seems code works. Have you check the connection? Did your device request the internet permission?

Comment: everything looks good. I don't know why

Comment: Maybe you could check that how to config WCF on Xamarin. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/wcf

Comment: I change my entire project REST API now.